# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str', when adding session data to Flask, Heroku

Tags: python, session, flask, heroku, jinja2

I'm building a Flask application that is being deployed to heroku. In the app, the user can post 'logs' to the page which include a message and the current time. The logs are passed through render_template via the user's session as follows:

```
    entry = (request.form['content'], datetime.now())
    session[id(entry)] = entry
    return render_template('index.html', logs=session)
```

The logs are received in the html as follows:

```
<div id="LogSheet">
  <center><table>
    {% if logs %}
    <p>{{logs | length}} Total Logs</p>
    <tr>
      <th>LogID</th>
      <th>Message</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
      {% for log in logs %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{log}}</td>
        <td>{{logs[log][0]}}</td>
        <td>{{logs[log][1].date()}}</td>
        <td>{{logs[log][1].time()}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </table></center>
</div>
```

When I am testing this on the localhost WSGI it works fine: I can add multiple logs in the same session and have separate concurrent and isolated sessions running. However when I deploy to heroku, I can only add one log. When I try adding a second log the server throws a 500 Internal Server Error with the following logs:

```
2020-08-09T14:21:01.492119+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)

2020-08-09T14:21:01.492119+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps

2020-08-09T14:21:01.492119+00:00 app[web.1]:     return cls(

2020-08-09T14:21:01.492119+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode

2020-08-09T14:21:01.492120+00:00 app[web.1]:     chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

2020-08-09T14:21:01.492120+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode

2020-08-09T14:21:01.492120+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _iterencode(o, 0)

2020-08-09T14:21:01.492121+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

I understand that the < comparitor cannot be used between different data types 'int' and 'str'. But I'm not sure which part of the code is producing this error. I tried removing the `<p>{{logs | length}} Total Logs</p>` as this is checking the length of the logs (session) dictionary, but it still throws the same error, so I'm not sure if its from my jinja2.

Is there some part of the dictionary that isn't being JSON serialized?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: I also tried changing `datetime.now()` to `int(time.time())` because I know datetime objects are not usually JSON serializable, however the exact same error occurs when using `int(time.time())`, and just grabbing `<td>{{logs[log][1]}}</td>` in html

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely an error arising from your script. The error happens in [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f2e161c27964a59bc5ab20d96f87ba5862c6222d/Lib/json/encoder.py#L413) function and as you mentioned

> I can only add one log. When I try adding a second log the server throws a 500 Internal Server Error with the following logs:

This means that on the second attempt there's an inadvertent mistake, likely from the data retrieved here `request.form['content']`. Try and find the contents of this line on Heroku and analyze the data anomaly in the 1st and 2nd time and you should see where the mistake is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link to showing how _iterencode works. Could you clarify why you suspect request.form['content']? Is it because my entry is a tuple?

Comment: That was just my guess, I am not entirely sure. The difference in contents is whats causing the error and you should also look at [cleaning the form data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data) . Entry as a tuple should not be a problem in my view.

Comment: @rmd_po was this error solved? Can you update the status?